# SQL*Server Constant values for user defined scalar functions - performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have a query that performs quite nicely when run like this:

```
SELECT YADAYADA FROM MYTABLE WHERE FVAL <= 100 AND TVAL >= 100
```

Since there's an index for (FVAL,TVAL), the query is totally optimal as a nonclustered index seek for the whole query.

Now, it'd be nice to use a constant returned from a user defined function here. The function will return a constant value for the *entire transaction*, not just this query. But doing this:

```
SELECT YADAYADA FROM MYTABLE WHERE FVAL <= dbo.myVal() AND TVAL >= dbo.myVal()
```

Yields suboptimal results - the query plan no longer nicely runs as an index seek, but instead insists on seeking and then *filtering*, which is obviously **MUCH** slower - even though in this instance my function is defined as returning a constant value in this really simple case.

I've tried using a BETWEEN clause - no better. I've tried table-valued functions, no better (in fact, the query plan gets rapidly more complex).

Is there *any* way of persuading SQL*Server that 'hey buddy, this is a **constant** value we're getting here, and to optimize the plan accordingly??

Answer (score 1):

The best that you could do would be to declare a variable within the query, assign the value of the UDF to that variable, then use the variable in the query.

Comment: I could do that - but ultimately this SQL is also hidden within a view (hence the need to use a UDF in the first place, it's actually being pulled from context_info).. and I can't put a DECLARE in a view. I could put the whole thing in a user TDF or stored proc - which would then hide all the other columns from the query optimizer :-(

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can get what you want. It sounds like you're going to have to perform whatever lookups the UDF would perform as joins in the view instead.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is trying to be clever and suggests what will be the values for the query, but sometimes developer knows better.

The following concept should help you

```
DECLARE @fval INT
DECLARE @tval INT
SET @fval = dbo.myVal()
SET @tval = dbo.myVal()

SELECT YADAYADA FROM MYTABLE WHERE FVAL <= @fval AND TVAL >= @tval
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR(@fval= 100, @tval = 100))
```